# Consume Azure ML web service through JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, web-services, azure

Trying to get some data from [this](https://studio.azureml.net/apihelp/workspaces/7423658e86cd4ac68698915b782c1667/webservices/d5a9f427416f43afa0e2eae67deb9ce5/endpoints/b7125f6db3aa400b928e7e3907b19c27/score) Azure web service. Here is the error I get:

[image]

Code for calling through Angular:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/7423658e86cd4ac68698915b782c1667/services/b7125f6db3aa400b928e7e3907b19c27/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + apiKey
    },
    data: dataString
}

$http(req).then(function(res){
   console.log("res", res);
}, function(err){
   console.log("err", err);
})
```

Where `dataString` is a JSON string exactly as in the sample data in the given link.

Googling didn't really help me but I guess this is some kind of a CORS problem. I have CORS enabled on localhost through Chrome plugin. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey did you get any success on this?

Answer (score 0):

CORS have to be enabled at the API Level